# ImagePicker.showImagePicker is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to use ImagePicker.showImagePicker and I get an Exception:

> ImagePicker.showImagePicker is not a function

My code looks something like

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
console.log('Response = ', response);
if (response.didCancel) {
  console.log('User cancelled image picker');
} else if (response.error) {
  console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
} else if (response.customButton) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image Picker migration from 2.x.x to 3.x.x removed showImagePicker from the API.
Use launchCamera or launchImageLibrary

See https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker

Comment: So they removed the feature we can select where we will get the image e.g. camera, gallery etc.